# Measuring the volume of downloaded data

Tags: java, network-programming, bandwidth

I'm currently searching for a way of *measuring the amount of downloaded data* on my computer while i am connected to the network / the Internet.

I'd need a method that would work either for Mac OS X or Windows XP/Vista and can't manage to find anything in the Java API related to that kind of feature. I hope you'll be able to help me :)

Thanks !

Comment: I think your question will get voted to be moved to superuser.com unless you clarify more about what type of API you are looking for. I noticed that the question is tagged with Java - are you trying to do this within a Java application?

Comment: Yes I didn't specify that cause I used the Java tag and thought it was enough. I'm searching for any means to perform such a task using the java api

Answer (score 1):

I've once created my own DU meter using Java. I read the output of

> NET STATISTICS

(command line) and parsed it. Running this task every second and calculating the difference in **Bytes Received** does the trick. Rather crude yes, but it worked.

Only works on Windows of course. I'm sure there's some command to run on Mac.

Comment: Hum yes, one solution would be to use a win/*nix console line and parse the return value...but I thought that maybe the java api would provide such a method and prevent me from making the whole parsing stuff

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a cross platform way.
To measure the amount of traffic you need to monitor the data of the network driver/subsystem.
On windows this will be "net statistics" on linux "ifconfig" but the output is of course not the same.